# Select date closest to date in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one having a entry date, and the other with an effective date. What I need to do is select the row were the entrydate is closest to the effective date. The only resource I can find is row_number() which does not seem to work in MySQL.

data

```
             Table A              Table B
           id    effdate         id    Aid    entrydate
           1     2015-10-19      1     1       2015-12-17
                                 2     1       2015-12-18
                                 3     1       2015-12-20
```

What I am trying to do is select

```
id    effdate      entrydate
1     2015-10-19   2015-12-17
```

So far I have tried using min() on entrydate, but it will just time out.

```
SELECT a.id, a.effdate, b.entrydate
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b on a.id = b.Aid
```

Comment: How do you want to handle ties if one is 1 date over and the other 1 date less?

Comment: The way the date is input the entrydate will always be after the effdate

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.effdate, b.entrydate
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b on a.id = b.Aid
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(entrydate, effdate) ASC
         -- you might want to order here by additional fields to break the ties
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If entry date is always greater than the effective date you can use the following

```
select a.id, a.effdate, b.entrydate from aa a, bb b
where a.id = b.aid 
  and b.entrydate = (select Min(bi.entrydate) 
                     from bb bi 
                     where bi.id = a.id
                    );
```